# How can I write twice on the same pipe?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I want parent to read from standard input and write it on pipe then the child read from this pipe and convert it to upper case and send it back on another pipe to the parent then the parent print it on standard output then write more one time.

The parent doesn't write anthor time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define bufsize 200

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    char buf[bufsize];
    char buf2[bufsize];
    int x;
    int child;
    int fd[2];
    int fd1[2];
    int nbytes,mbytes;
    int i,j,k;
    int status=0;

    if(pipe(fd)==-1)
        printf("pipe");
    if(pipe(fd1)==-1)
        printf("pipe");

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1 : printf("fork");
        case 0:{
            //for(k=1;k<3;k++)
            //{close(fd[1]);
            nbytes = read(fd[0], buf, bufsize);   

            for(i=0;i<=strlen(buf);i++){
                if(buf[i]>=97&&buf[i]<=122)
                buf[i]=buf[i]-32;
            }//end for

            close(fd1[0]);
            write(fd1[1], buf, nbytes);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);   

        }//end child

        default:{
            for(j=1;j<3;j++){
                close(fd[0]);
                printf("Enter any thing:\n");
                x=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, bufsize);
                write(fd[1],buf,x);

                close(fd1[1]);
                mbytes = read(fd1[0], buf, bufsize);   
                close(fd1[0]); 
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, mbytes);
            }
            //wait(status);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }//end default
    }//end switch
}
```

Comment: Please do not save spacebar but indent your code properly so that it is possible to read whatever you're intending to do there.

Comment: Also note that on fork failure you'd also run the code for `case 0:`! Add a break at the end of `case -1:`.

Comment: I don't understand, what you, people (not indenting the code) using as your text editor? Windows Notepad? Most of the modern code editors are just doing it for you, and you have to make some effort to prevent it from them.

Comment: 'Means you ain't gonna show'

Comment: `fd` and `fd1` are *terrible* names for your two arrays of file descriptors. But your issue is that you close the file descriptors the first time through your `for` loop. So the second time, you are reading and writing to closed file descriptors, which is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write twice to the same pipe, *don't close it* after you write to it the first time. Only close it when you are done.